# paraview install problem

Tags: software-installation

[image]

[image]

When I run Paraview for OpenFOAM, I use the method that is on the website, but it doesn't run, it just shows the line in the first figure. Could anyone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: guys i retype the command "paraview" it shows the same thing

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version? What was wrong with [package from official repositories](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&exact=1&searchon=names&keywords=paraview)? Why `/opt/...` is involved into proccess?

Comment: my version is 20.04LTS , I don't know guy i just followed the step written by official package

Comment: then it become like this i don't know whether i should use WSL to open the ubuntu , before i watch the vedio provided by youtube, they just said use command by ununtu